# Angular 5 and animate sliding to the right

Tags: angular

I want to do animation on div, that changes width of element from 100% to 20%, collapsing from left to right side and right border of div should stay on the same place. I created animation that collapse div from right to left by changing width from 100% to 20%:

```
export const CardSlideAnimation = trigger('cardSlideAnimation',
[
    state('slideToRight', style({
      width: '20%'
    })),
    transition('* => *', animate('2000ms ease-out'))
]);
```

I dont have idea how to collapse div from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

On the element that is being animated, have it `float: right`. This will have the element stay to the right and when it collapses it will collapse to the right.

### [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmjvos)

Comment: The old demo link was bad but I updated it with the correct one.